# Alternative to Nz and IIF(Is Null)

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, ms-access, ado.net

I have a query in Access in which one of the fields contains a subquery returning the sum of a specific field from a related table. The result of the subquery is used in further calculations in the main query.

This is used in a homemade reporting application in VB.Net (C# would be fine) using ADO.Net. Queries are stored in a table in Access to allow us to correct small bugs or adding temporary features related to the data without publishing our application again.

The problem is that it's possible that the subquery returns no result (null). Furthermore, a null value used in calculations will also return a null value. Therefore, I need to replace the null value by 0 if that's needed. I added `NZ(subquery, 0)`, but ADO.Net throws the following exception:

```
Undefined function 'NZ' in expression
```

I learned that it's not possible to use a VBA function in ADO.Net since it's part of the Access.Application object.

I also considered using `IIF(subquery Is Null, 0, subquery)`, but that would force me to duplicate the subquery, and force Access to execute the subquery twice *(probably)*. Since the subquery is rather complex (and so is the main query), I want to avoid that, at least for the sake of readability, if not performance.

Is there another way to replace a null value by another value, or to make sure my subquery will always return a non-null sum even with no matching record?

Comment: Alter the subquery SQL so it returns 0 instead of Null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, there's no other way. The cleanest method is going to be

```
Iif(IsNull([Data]), 0, [Data])
```

NZ is a function specific to the Access code library, so you won't be able to use it.

Comment: I ended up giving my subquery its own field, and using the field as `IIF(field Is Null, 0, field)` in the calculations.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int? x = null;

// Set y to the value of x if x is NOT null; otherwise,
// if x == null, set y to -1.
int y = x ?? -1;
```

To learn more, see [microsoft help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

Answer (score 1):

Try using ?? like below:

```
         double? nullableVar=null;
         double nonNullableVar;
         nonNullableVar = (nullableVar ?? 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my custom function ez: [Undefined function 'Nz' in expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584355/undefined-function-nz-in-expression/59234971#59234971). Here it is:

```
Public Function ez(ByVal vVal1 As Variant, Optional ByVal vVal2 As Variant = 0) As Variant
    If VBA.IsNull(vVal1) Or VBA.Len(vVal1) = 0 Then
        ez = vVal2
    Else
        ez = vVal1
    End If
End Function
```

As you can see, it goes a little further than the original function since it not only considers the second value if the first one is null but also if it is empty

Also, the default return value is 0 while with Nz is an empty string.